# How to keep pyglet from clearing the screen?

Tags: python, pyglet

I want to draw a scene and sequentially add lines to it. But pyglet keeps updating without control :( , so all I get is blinks

```
from pyglet.gl import *

window=pyglet.window.Window()

def drawline():
    ...

@window.event
def on_draw():
    drawline()

pyglet.app.run()
```

should I change the decorator(if there exist options) or what?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to draw your lines each time the window is redrawn as they won't be retained. You're probably better off using batches of vertex lists and adding to them. See [here](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/vertex_lists.html) and [here](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/batched_rendering.html) for details.